# Grab HTML SPAN with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<td>
     <input type="textbox" name="birthyear" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />
      <span>←Year: 1993</span>
</td>
```

What I'm trying to do is grab the 1093 property with jquery.
I have tried innerhtml, but was not successful.
If possible, how can I grab that 1993 without the '←Year:' and put into a variable?

Comment: Do you want a solution for more spans and to put years in array ??

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
var year = $("span").text().split(' ')[1];
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but what if there's more than one span on the page?

Comment: put an id to your span. And use `$("#spanid").text().split(' ')[1];`

Comment: @AnthonyRad then you need to find a way to specify which one you want

Comment: But what if there's no spanid.  How can I parse without it?

Comment: @AnthonyRad without an ID, you need to find another way to identify the span. `input[name='birthyear'] + span` seems safe

Comment: @AnthonyRad You _can_ parse without it. However Barmar answered your original question to its fullest extent and if you find his answer satisfactory to the original question you should consider accepting it. If you have a different question (like - how you can apply what he said to multiple spans (How do I process the selection of multiple elements' text()in jQuery?) you should ask it in a different question or search for it.

Comment: If there's more than one span, you need to use a more specific selector. It all depends on your page layout, and what is triggering it. For instance, if the user clicks on something, you can use DOM traversal methods in jQuery to find the associated span. I thought the part you didn't understand was how to get the year out of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

One methode is

```
<span id="spanID">←Year: 1993</span>
```

and use jquery

```
$("#spanid").text().split(' ')[1];
```

If you are sure about the text and no id for span then you can use

```
$('span:contains("your text")').text().split(' ')[1];
```

Comment: I don't really see what you add here over Barmar's answer on which you commented on (with something similar). This does the exact same thing (`.text().split(' ')[1];`). If you could elaborate a bit on the difference between the two answers that could be great.

Comment: 1: Providing id (`spanid`) to your span    2: span which contains your text Eg: `$('span:contains("1993")')`. Since you are ot able to put id for span.

Answer (score 0):

give the span an ID, then...

```
$("#spanID").text().split(' ')[1];
```